# Python: How to draw coordinates using tkinter whilst reading from a .txt

Tags: python, text, tkinter, coordinates

First time user. I'm a grad student at George Mason and I've been greatly aided, and impressed by the community here so I thought that I would pose a question.

I'm trying to draw points specified from a textfile using tkinter (the points are specified at the top of the code but I put them in a textfile). My assignment requires me to project the points but I want to go a step further and have them read directly from my variables so if the .txt changes they change aswell. My problem is that I'm not sure how to parse the variables to so tkinter can see them.

```
Here is the code:

"""
Read the following data (I put them into .txt first):
Polyline;
1: 1603714.835939442,142625.48838266544; 1603749.4678153452,142620.21243656706; 1603780.3769339535,142607.37201781105; 1603801.475846678,142582.27024446055; 1603830.4767344964,142536.14692804776;
2: 1602514.2066492266,142330.66992144473; 1602521.4127475217,142414.92978276964; 1602520.1146955898,142433.93817959353; 1602501.3840010355,142439.12358761206; 1602371.6780588734,142417.84858870413; 1602351.6610373354,142408.02716448065; 1602334.5180692307,142388.58748627454; 1602331.6999511716,142376.66073128115; 1602334.8067251327,142348.965322732; 1602338.308919772,142323.6111663878; 1602349.0226452332,142314.50124930218; 1602363.9090971674,142310.79584660195; 1602514.2066492266,142330.66992144473;

The following code define a function 'readPolylineFile' to read out data one line by one line
The readPolylineFile function will return two polylines

In addtion, try....except...finally are used to catch the exceptions
"""
import math
class Points:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x,self.y = x, y
class Polyline:
    def __init__(self, points =[] ):
        self.points = points
    def getLength(self):
        i = 0
        length =  0.0
        while i < len(self.points)-1:
            length += math.sqrt((self.points[i+1].x -self.points[i].x)**2 + (self.points[i+1].y -self.points[i].y)**2 )
            i += 1
        return length

## function to read out data one line by one line
## return polylines list
def readPolylineFile(fileName):
    ## Declare variables that will be used outside of try blocks
    polylines = []  ## empty polyline list to keep all polylines
    f = None # empty file object
    try:    
        f = open(fileName, 'r')  ## Open the file and assign the return object to f      
        firstPolyLineNum = 0
        index = 0
        for line in f:
            index += 1
            if index == 1: ## Pass the first line
                continue       
            coords = line.split(':')[1]            
            eachcoords = coords.split(';')          
            coordsLen = len(eachcoords)
            points = [] ## Declare a points list to keep the points for each polyline
            for i in range(coordsLen-1):
                singlecoords = eachcoords[i]
                xCoord = singlecoords.split(',')[0]
                yCoord = singlecoords.split(',')[1]
                print singlecoords
                try:
                    point = Points(float(xCoord),float(yCoord))
                    points.append(point)

                except ValueError:
                   print 'Can not convert non-number to float'
                except TypeError:
                   print 'Object type can not conver to float' 
            ## Create a polyline object based on the points
            polyline = Polyline(points)
            polylines.append(polyline)

    except IOError: ##File does not exist
        print 'IO Error while opening or reading the file'
    finally:
        if f:  ## If file object exist, close the file
            print 'Input .txt has been read and is now closed......'
            f.close()

    return polylines  ## Return the polylines


polylines = readPolylineFile('F://GMU Fall 2013/GGS 650/HW6/input.txt')

try: 
    ## Get the first polyline
    polyLine1 = polylines[0]
    lengthForFirstPoly = polyLine1.getLength()
    print "length for first polyline (first 5 coordinates) -> ", lengthForFirstPoly

    ## Gets the points for second polyline
    polyLine2 = polylines[1]
    lengthForSecondPoly = polyLine2.getLength()
    print "length for Second polyline (last 13 coordinates) -> ", lengthForSecondPoly

except:
    print "error in processing polyline objects created"

from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master2 = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=800, height=600)
w.pack()
w.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)

w = Canvas(master2, width=800, height=600)
w.pack()
w.create_line(0, 0, 200, 297)
mainloop()
```

Comment: You've dumped a whole ton of code on us, and haven't told us which part doesn't work right, or even how it doesn't work. Please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for some hints on making your question easier to answer.

Comment: What's the actual problem / error?

Comment: Sorry about the long code. I didn't realize that convention existed here, although, it makes sense as shorter code is easier to troubleshoot. The problem isn't an error, it's that I don't know what to plug into tkinter (bottom) to draw my coordinates (top) and I don't want to use static values even though that would be enough to get a good grade because I'm paying for grad school myself so I actually want to learn something. By being able to read coordinates from a .txt and draw them I would have a useful skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create a method in Polyline that returns the coordinates of all of it's points as a flat list, then use that to create your line.

Here's a quick and dirty example of returning a flattened list of coordinates:

```
class Polyline(self):
    ...
    def getCoordinates(self):
        coords = []
        for point in self.points:
            coords.append(point.x)
            coords.append(point.y)
        return coords
```

Here's how to create a line on a canvas for every polyline:

```
for polyline in polylines:
    canvas.create_line(polyline.getCoordinates())
```